# How to migrate from textScaleFactor to TextScalar.scale

Tags: flutter, dart

`textScaleFactor` was recently deprecated and one is supposed to use the `TextScaler.scale(double fontSize)` instead, but not all places that take a `textScaleFactor` seemingly supports the new way.

For example `ButtonStyleButton.scaledPadding` is taking in a `textScaleFactor`, but what `fontSize` are you supposed to call `TextScalar.scale` with to pass in as the scale factor there?

```dart
    ButtonStyleButton.scaledPadding(
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)?.textScaler.scale(??),
    );
```

Previously:

```dart
    ButtonStyleButton.scaledPadding(
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)?.textScaleFactor,
    );
```

Comment: Opened this one: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale method of TextScaler takes your fontSize and scales it with the text scale factor.

That means if you pass it `1`, it will return the textScaleFactor.

**Before**

```
double textScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
```

**After**

```
double textScaleFactor = MediaQuery.textScalerOf(context).scale(1);
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, I don't know why I didn't think of that before. Marked you answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem. For the alternative maybe we can do this

```
final textScaleFactor = TextScaler.scale(10) / 10;
```

Comment: Since the scaling is not linear, the outcome would differ depending on what number you choose.

Comment: This seems to be the suggested way from the docs, I must have missed it. It feels a bit sketchy though. Anyhow, I don't think there is another way to do it, so I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio offers context menu autocomplete to migrate from deprecated implementation:

BEFORE:

```
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    textScaleFactor: hasFontScaling ? 1.5 : 1,
  ),
  child: card,
);
```

AFTER:

```
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    textScaler: TextScaler.linear(hasFontScaling ? 1.5 : 1),
  ),
  child: card,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using textScaleFactor on Text widget, here is the updated code.

Old:
`Text('Ref Name', textScaleFactor: 0.8)`

New:
`Text('Ref Name', textScaler: TextScaler.linear(0.8)`

Answer (score 0):

There is still global way to define scale level for all widgets. Note, this may not be the best way to handle all scaling issues as it will limit user defined accessibility scaling. However, this defines scale level for text and widgets as very high user accesibility values coming from mobile OS settings may make the app unusable or distort the UI design.
Before it was like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(      
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        final mediaQueryObj = MediaQuery.of(context);
        final scaleRange = mediaQueryObj.textScaleFactor.clamp(0.5, 2.0);  // set min and max scale values here


        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            textScaleFactor: scaleRange,
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
```

Now, as the Flutter textScaleFactor is deprected due to new requirement of Android 14's scaling changes, we need to use textScaler and text scale clamping:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MediaQuery.withClampedTextScaling(
        minScaleFactor: 0.7, // set min scale value here
  maxScaleFactor: 2,  // set max scale value here
        child: MaterialApp(

  )
          },
```

Comment: This is good for people to know, but it is not an answer to the question.